# `URLSessionDelegate` methods are not called

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, urlsession

Please, note that I've checked previous answers and I am *not using callbacks* in the code. In this case the `delegate` methods should be called

Environment **iOS 14.4.2**

URL is valid. File is downloaded. Just the delegate not get called.

The example code is below:

```
final class Downloader: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate {

    private lazy var urlSession = URLSession(
        configuration: .default,
        delegate: self,
        delegateQueue: .main
    )
    private var downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask?

    func beginDownload(url: URL) {
        downloadTask = urlSession.downloadTask(with: url)
        downloadTask!.resume()
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        // NEVER CALLED
    }
}
```

Comment: how is the `Downloader` class created? Is it retained? perhaps it gets deallocated right after being created

Comment: @Adam, yes. It is retained. I had the same assumption.

Comment: @Sh_Khan, Downloader is created and retained in another place.

Comment: Are you sure the download task actually finishes at all? Also, the method you're implementing is part of `URLSessionDownloadDelegate`, not `URLSessionDelegate`, so you should declare conformance to `URLSessionDownloadDelegate` as well.

Comment: @DávidPásztor, you're right. The problem was I had conformance to `URLSessionDataDelegate` instead of `URLSessionDownloadDelegate`

Comment: @DávidPásztor, please, add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL)` method you're implementing is part of `URLSessionDownloadDelegate`, not `URLSessionDelegate`, so you should declare conformance to `URLSessionDownloadDelegate` as well in order for the delegate call to occur.